# How do you access resources like .json files in a Typescript Nest.js project?

Tags: nestjs

Using this resource https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#assets , I'm having a hard time understanding how I'm to access the files from the `dist` folder.

in the `nest-cli.json` file:

```
{
   "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
   "sourceRoot": "src",
   "compilerOptions": {
      "assets": [{"include": "**/*.json", "outDir": "./dist/src"}]
   }
}
```

I'm then just calling the directory with some code like this

```
readFileSync(`./dist/src/jsonFiles/${fileName}`
```

I'm more used to the Java Maven world where there was a resources folder, and a formal way of accessing files from the resources folder. My concern is that though my current implementation works when I'm running it locally, the files won't be accessible in the production environment because of how the build/deployment process works there.

Is there a proper nest.js way of storing non-TypeScript files like `.json` files, and how is that way supposed to be done in order to avoid production environment issues?

Comment: I'm not sure what your build process is, but `nest build` from the same directory as the package.json should make the files accessible in the dist folder relative to the directory node is started from. My yarn start:prod runs `node dist/main`, so I can access the files from `path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist/src/jsonFiles/...')`